# Are all the solutions produced by Mathematica?

Tags: diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

Here is a very strong and impressive result of the `Reduce` command.

```
Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == 841*(a*b + 1), {a, b}, PositiveIntegers]
```

performs `(a == 24389 && b == 29)` and 6 infinite series of the solutions, one of these is (The results are too big for $\LaTeX$.)

> `(C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 &&  a == (1/1414554)(-(24389/ 2) (-707277 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] + 841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  707277 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] - 841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1]) -  20511033/ 2 (-841 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] + Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  841 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1])) && b == -(1/1414554) 29 (-707277 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] + 841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  707277 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] - 841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1]))`

This is problem 16 from [Kvant 2020, # 10, p. 42](https://kvant.ras.ru/pdf/2020/2020-10.pdf) (in Russian). Its solution is given in p. 60 ibid .
However, no explicit formulas are presented there, but only an algorithm to obtain all the solutions in `PositiveIntegers`.

My questions are: are all the solutions produced by `Reduce`? how to establish it? I hope the answer to the first question is yes.

Comment: @Moo: Cross-asked there. However, I think it suits here too.

Comment: @Moo: One may use the Google translator to this end. The problem consists in different approaches done by Mathematica (series of explicit solutions) and by hand (an algorithm). I don't see how to compare thes.

Comment: @Moo: Here is a start: The solutions $a,b$ (provided $a\le b$) are
those and only those pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ that for
each $n \in \mathbb N $ are calculated by the formulas:$a_n=b_{n-1}, b_n=k^2b_{n-1}-a_{n-1},a_0=0,b_0=k$, here $k=29$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers satisfying
$$a^2+b^2=29^2(ab+1),$$
then the dicriminant of this quadratic in $b$ is a perfect square, so
$$c^2=(29^2a)^2-4(a^2-29^2)=(3\cdot281\cdot839)a^2+2^2\cdot29^2,$$
for some positive integer $X$. Then $(X,Y)=(c,a)$ is a solution to the Pell equation
$$X^2-dY^2=2^2\cdot29^2,$$
where $d=3\cdot281\cdot389$, which can be solved by standard methods.

Comment: Alternatively, multiplying everything by $4$ we get
$$(2a)^2-(2^2\cdot29^2)ab+(2b)^2=2^2\cdot29^2,$$
so for $(X,Y)=(2a-29^2b,b)$ we get
$$X^2-dY^2=2^2\cdot29^2.$$

Comment: @Servaes: Can you give a complete answer to the question?  If yes, please present it.

Answer (score 1):

Up to the cited algorithm, the solutions $a,b$ (provided $a\le b$) are
those and only those pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ that for
each $n \in \mathbb N $ are calculated by the formulas:$a_n=b_{n-1},\, b_n=k^2b_{n-1}-a_{n-1},\,a_0=0,\,b_0=k$, here $k=29$.

The `RSolve` command of Mathematica cracks it:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == b[n - 1], b[n] == 29^2*b[n - 1] - a[n - 1], a[0] == 0,
b[0] == 29}, {a, b}, n]
```

$$a(n)=-\frac{29 \left(2 \left(\sqrt{707277}+841\right)\right)^{-n} \left(4^n-\left(\sqrt{707277}+841\right)^{2 n}\right)}{\sqrt{707277}},$$ $$b(n)=29 U_n\left(\frac{841}{2}\right). $$
in the above $U_n$ stands for [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). It remains to compare this solution with the solution found by `Reduce`.

Comment: @WillJagi: Can you give a complete answer to the question? If yes, please present it.